How to call @vercel/og image endpoint from getStaticProps?
I have set up dynamically generated OG images that I also want to use as header image for my blog posts. I have set it up using @vercel/og in Next.js, but it takes forever to dynamically call the API endpoint /api/create-og-image upon page load. Like 1-2 seconds, which is way too long for SEO or good user experience.
/api/create-image-with-text.jsx
export default async function handler(req) {
    return new ImageResponse(imageHTMLResult, {
        width: 2400,
        height: 1260
    }
}

The endpoint returns an ImageResponse object, which works fine to plug in to an  component directly, as:
<Image src={"/api/create-image-with-text-1/?title=${blogTitle}"} ../>
In order to speed up the page and use the @vercel/og generated image as header image for blog posts, I want to simply pre-render the images using getStaticProps and pass a reference to the component.
/pages/blog/[blogPost].jsx:
export async function getStaticProps({ params, locale }) {
     
    const ogImage = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/create-image-with-text/?title=${title}`)
    const ogImageJson = await ogImage.json();
    return {
         props: {
             ogImage: ogImageJson,
         }
    }

It seems like the format is not able to be serialized. So I wanted to see if someone has done this or can figure out how?

Post the response of the ogImage fetch - is it possible the response needs further prep before it can be serialized?
